# Remove elements from an array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

So I just need to remove matching pairs in an array. My array consists of a deck of cards. If an element is a pair, for example if the array $sortedHand is: SA DA C9 C8

Because their is a pair of aces in spades and diamonds. I need to remove it from the array $sortedHand

So then the new variable maybe $removedHand would only contain C9 C8. Hope you understand

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a cards=(null SA HA DA CA SK HK DK CK SQ HQ DQ CQ SJ HJ DJ CJ ST HT DT CT S9 H9 D9 C9 S8 H8 D8 C8 S7 $
declare -a sortedHand

for i
do
    hand+=' '${cards[i]}
done

set -- $(printf "%d\n" "$@" | sort -n)

for i
do
    sortedHand+=' '${cards[i]}
done

echo The hand is $hand
echo Sorted hand $sortedHand
```

Edit I have added code

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a cards=(null SA HA DA CA SK HK DK CK SQ HQ DQ CQ SJ HJ DJ CJ ST HT DT CT S9 H9 D9 C9 S8 H8 D8 C8 S7 $

for i
do
    hand+=' '${cards[i]}
done

set -- $(printf "%d\n" "$@" | sort -n)

for i
do
    sortedHand+=' '${cards[i]}
done

echo The hand is $hand
echo Sorted hand $sortedHand

for((i=0; i -le ${#hand}; ++i))
do
    for((j=0; j -le ${#hand}; ++j))
    do
            if [ $i == $j ]
            then continue
            fi
            if [ ${hand[i]:1:1} == ${hand[j]:1:1} ]
            then continue 2
            fi
    done
    sortedHand+=' '${hand[i]}
done

echo Remaining cards $sortedHand
```

This is the output I get

```
turtle.sh 1 2 5 10
The hand is SA HA SK HQ
Sorted hand SA HA SK HQ
./turtle.sh: line 23: ((: i -le 12: syntax error in expression (error token is "12")
Remaining cards SA HA SK HQ
```

Help please

Another Edit

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a cards=(null SA HA DA CA SK HK DK CK SQ HQ DQ CQ SJ HJ DJ CJ ST HT DT CT S9 H9 D9 C9 S8 H8 D8 C8 S7 $

for i
do
    hand+=' '${cards[i]}
done

set -- $(printf "%d\n" "$@" | sort -n)

for i
do
    sortedHand+=' '${cards[i]}
done

echo The hand is $hand
echo Sorted hand $sortedHand

for((i=0; i-le${#sortedHand}; ++i))
do
    for((j=0; j-le${#sortedHand}; ++j))
    do
            if [ $i == $j ]
            then continue
            fi
            if [ ${sortedHand[i]:1:1} == ${sortedHand[j]:1:1} ]
            then continue 2
            fi
    done
    remainingHand+=${hand[i]}
done

echo Remaining cards $remainingHand
```

The outcome of above code

```
turtle.sh 1 2 5 10
The hand is SA HA SK HQ
Sorted hand SA HA SK HQ
Remaining cards
```

Thanks for all your help

Also tried your exact code

```
turtle.sh 1 2 5 10
The hand is SA HA SK HQ
Sorted hand SA HA SK HQ
Remaining cards SA HA SK HQ
```

Comment: Shell script is an odd choice for this particular task.

Comment: Trust me I would much rather do it in Java but its for my assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through `hand` and loop through `hand` again from the current index of the outer loop.
Compare the second letter of the elements and add index to `sortedHand` if no matches were found.

That would look like this:

```
cards=(null SA HA DA CA SK HK DK CK SQ HQ DQ CQ SJ HJ DJ CJ ST HT DT CT S9 H9 D9 C9 S8 H8 D8 C8 S7)

 for i in $@ # $@ are all passed arguments, if this gives issues try putting quotes around it
do hand+=(cards[i])
done

for((i=0; i < ${#hand[@]}; ++i)) # C style loop, uses i and <, not $i and -le.
do
    for((j=0; j < ${#hand[@]}; ++j)) # ${#hand[@]} is the number of elements in the array hand. 
    do
        if [ $i == $j ]
        then continue
        fi
        if [ ${hand[i]:1:1} == ${hand[j]:1:1} ]
        then continue 2
        fi
    done
    sortedHand+=(${hand[i]})
done

echo ${hand[@]} # ${hand[@]} is the array in string representation.
echo ${sortedHand[@]}
```

Comment: Tried this but it just has the same result as other sorted hand. Maybe I am doing it wrong

Comment: Oh oops I made a mistake starting the second loop from the first loop's current index. I edited it, should work now.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I edited the question. I would really appreciate if you could help me because I am getting an error. Thanks so much again

Comment: Oh I see what it is, I'll edit the code. I forgot the $ for the looping variables in the for loop.

Comment: Actually I figured it out. I just needed to close the gap between i -le. But now it still doesn't work lol

Comment: I updated the post once again. Please correct what I have done wrong. I am super confused

Comment: In the two for loops replace the i and j in "i -le ${#hand}" with $i and $j.

Comment: Ah, I debugged it and found out a made a few huge derps. I fixed it, I promise this version will work :)

Comment: I feel like I am so close. The code works but only when I specify the array on top like you did. I cant get it to work with the argument parsed array of hand.

Comment: I edited it to accept input parameters and select the cards to put i  the hand, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: It has worked. Thank you so much for all your help. You are the best!

Answer (score 0):

To delete an element from an array, use the `unset` command (with quotes to avoid pathname expansion):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a cards=(null SA HA DA CA SK HK DK CK SQ HQ DQ CQ SJ HJ DJ CJ ST HT DT CT S9 H9 D9 C9 S8 H8 D8 C8 S7 $)

echo "${cards[@]}" # null SA HA DA CA SK HK DK CK SQ HQ DQ CQ SJ HJ DJ CJ ST HT DT CT S9 H9 D9 C9 S8 H8 D8 C8 S7 $
unset 'cards[1]'
echo "{cards[@]}" # null HA DA CA SK HK DK CK SQ HQ DQ CQ SJ HJ DJ CJ ST HT DT CT S9 H9 D9 C9 S8 H8 D8 C8 S7 $
```